# Error "t.haven_labelled()` not supported" when trying to substitute NA with mice package

Tags: r, error-handling, r-mice, r-haven

Total R noob here, trying to figure out how to implement mice package to account for NAs in my dataset.

This is my code so far (i left out the unimportant stuff like trimming the data set down to relevant variables, recoding etc.)

```
install.packages("haven")
install.packages("survey")
library(haven)
library(data.table)
library(survey)
library(car)

dat <- read_dta("ZA5270_v2-0-0.dta")
dat_wght <- svydesign(ids= ~1, data=dat, weights =~wghtpew)

install.packages("mice")
library(mice)

dat_wght[["variables"]]$sex = as.factor(dat_wght[["variables"]]$sex)

dat_imp <- mice(dat_wght[["variables"]], m=5, maxit=10)
```

The error message I get is:

```
iter imp variable
  1   1  px03Error in `t()`:
! `t.haven_labelled()` not supported.
```

I already did some research and apparantly it has to do with label values since `haven` package causes lots of weird problems. I already tried to remove all label values with `sapply(dat_wght[["variables"]], haven::zap_labels)`but the error still occurs (same when I try it with `remove_val_labels()`) Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I'm really grateful for every single piece of advice :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried applying `zap_labels()` to the entire dataframe? E.g. `dat_wght_clean <- zap_labels(dat_wght, user_na = FALSE); dat_wght_clean[["variables"]]$sex = as.factor(dat_wght_clean[["variables"]]$sex); dat_imp <- mice(dat_wght_clean[["variables"]], m=5, maxit=10)` ?

Comment: @jared_mamrot I tried your code, but it still doesn't work.  When I try to use 'sapply(dat_wght_clean[["variables"]], class)' to check, it still says '$px03
[1] "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double', so they still have that haven label.

Comment: @jared_mamrot However, I found out that if I run `dat_wght_[["variables"]]$spx03 = as.numeric(dat_wght[["variables"]]$spx03)` will change the error and apparently it will proceed to the next variable: I still get the same error, but with px01 instead of px03 (next column). So maybe I just need to find an easy way to label all columns as numeric first and then manually `sex` as factor, and then I should be good to go

Comment: Glad you sorted it out

Comment: Greetings! For your `read_data` file here, I don't see something reproducible to work with. Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so others can help faster. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Thanks for the info, I didn't know that yet. But I actually sorted it out: I created a new data table out of `dat` and labelled everything as numeric with `lapply`, then manually labelled `sex` as well as some other categorial variables as factors and by that got rid of the haven_labelled nonsense. Then I created the survey object and used `mice` on it

Comment: Glad to hear it. Perhaps you can post an answer if others will find it useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to try to drop all the value labels in the original data format before importing it to R with haven.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34146436)